# Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package quagga

Tags: linux, redhat, quagga

I am trying to install quagga on my Linux server and I am getting below errors:

```
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package quagga-0.98.6-11.el5.x86_64
error: %pre(quagga-0.98.6-11.el5.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status  1
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping quagga-0.98.6-11.el5
```

I tried everything and searched on net but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this problem many times on RHEL/Centos.

I had to create quagga user and groups as given below:

```
grep quagga /etc/passwd
quagga:x:92:92:Quagga routing suite:/var/run/quagga:/sbin/nologin

grep quagga /etc/group
quaggavt:x:85:
quagga:x:92:
```

And do "yum update quagga". This should work, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while installing wireshark. Wireshark creates a new user which was failing with the above error. The reason I found was:

```
ls -l /etc/group
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 476 Jul17 19:13 /etc/group
```

See the `.` in the end. That means "SELinux ACL". More info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/230559/what-does-the-dot-mean-at-the-end-of-rw-r-r-how-do-you-set-it-with-chmod).

Basically, this ACL prevents from accessing this directory even being a root user. To temporarily disable it:

```
sestatus # to check current status
sudo setenforce Permissive
sestatus
```

Thats it, now I can install Wireshark with yum just fine.